# sqlkata - Self Join; Add aliases while joining

Tags: sqlkata

What is the right way to do a self join using SQL KATA? Currently, I am only able to do the following

```
var query1 = new Query("Users");
var query = new Query("Users")
    .Join(query1.As("a"), j => j.On("a.Name", "Users.ParentName"))
    .Where("Name", "Sami");
```

But this generates the following query

```
SELECT
*
FROM
[Users]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
    *
    FROM
    [Users]
) AS [a] ON ([a].[Name] = [Users].[ParentName])
WHERE
[Name] = 'Sami'
```

Is it possible to achieve the following query?

```
SELECT
*
FROM
[Users] [a]
INNER JOIN [Users] [b] ON ([a].[ParentName] = [b].[Name])
WHERE
[a].[Name] = 'Sami'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create a separate query instance here, do it like any other table.
the key here is to use the `table as alias` syntax to instruct SqlKata that you are using a different alias.

```
var query = new Query("Users as a")
    .Join("Users as b", "a.ParentName", "b.Name")
    .Where("a.Name", "sami");
```

this will generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [Users] AS [a]
  INNER JOIN [Users] AS [b] ON [a].[ParentName] = [b].[Name]
WHERE
  [a].[Name] = 'sami'
```

check the following example directly on Sqlkata playground 
[Self Join Example on SqlKata Playground](https://sqlkata.com/playground?code=var%20query%20%3D%20new%20Query(%22Users%20as%20a%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.Join(%22Users%20as%20b%22%2C%20%22a.ParentName%22%2C%20%22b.Name%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.Where(%22a.Name%22%2C%20%22name%20here%22)%3B)